# Proxy for home use with specific needs

Tags: wifi, proxy

I'd like to set up a proxy at home that will allow for filtering and logging of internet access.  I currently have an old Eee PC running Lubuntu and serving as a wireless access point, among other services.  I do this by having a wired connection from the Eee PC to the WAN router (a Comcast cable modem) which is then shared to the wireless via ap-hotspot.  I would like to add to this a proxy which will provide at least the following capabilities:

1. Website filtering.  An "access forbidden" page is acceptable, but I'd prefer that blocked sites simply appear to time out.
2. Access logging by device ID
3. Access alerting
4. Log rotation

It seems like Squid should be able to do this, but I'd appreciate any additional pointers to good packages.  Better, if anyone has set something like this up, how has it gone for you?  Are there any other capabilities you've found useful?  My goal is to allow guests access but to ensure that our network is not used for anything sketchy.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a specific question ? There are several options for a proxy, you can use squid or privoxy. For what you want I suggest squid.

Answer (score 0):

I think QL Proxy from Diladele is very nice.  It's ICAP/Squid based and does everything you'd need and far more.  The last time I used it, it was fully functional without the purchase of a license, but that may have changed.   Just the same, it's worth a look.  It'll quickly and easily install on your Ubuntu system.

http://www.quintolabs.com/

If you are a bit savvy, you can learn from the configuration and adapt/reimplement it in such a way that a license is not required.